# Not able to log (both) textPayloads and jsonPayloads within the same log

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Context:

- Nodejs
- Viewing the logs within the Cloud Logs Veiwer
- I'm able to log textPayloads
- I'm able to log jsonPayloads
- I can't seem to log textPayloads and jsonPayloads
- If I set both, I end up getting an empty jsonPayload field value and the textPayload field is just not even there.

Setup:

- Note:

  ```
  const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging')
  const logging = new Logging({projectId: 'xyz'}) 
  let log = logging.log('zyx)
  ```
- With textPayload:

  ```
  metadata.textPayload = json
  const entry = log.entry(metadata, text)
  log.write(entry)
  ```
- With jsonPayload:

  ```
  metadata.jsonPayload = json
  const entry = log.entry(metadata, text)
  log.write(entry)
  ```
- With Both - trying a bunch of the field options:

  ```
  metadata.message = text
  metadata.textPayload = text 
  metadata.log = text 
  metadata.jsonPayload = json
  const entry = log.entry(metadata, text)
  log.write(entry)
  ```

I feel like it should be possible to do both, but perhaps i'm missing something?